# Applying shadow filter to container but not it's children

Tags: easeljs

I have an object composited from child containers. I want to apply shadow filter to the whole object, so that it falls around the object but not inside it, but what I get instead is every child of the main object having it's own shadow - inside and outside of the main object.

how do I create shadow only around an object but not around it's children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-composite any display object by using `cache()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/oquob0x4/

Comment: The clone() documentation confused me "Note that filters need to be defined before the cache is applied. Check out the Filter class for more information. "

Comment: Shadow isn't a `Filter` in EaselJS terms (I know that's a little weird). It's an effect that's built into canvas. That's why it isn't added to the filters list, but applied as a property.